# Apache2 ModRewrite Dynamic Url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I am trying to use htaccess to rewrite my url variables.

```
Example url http://example.com/assets/asset.php?id=9e233a25-994e-4262-8bfb-e477de1474ae
```

what I need is

```
http://example.com/assets/9e233a25-994e-4262-8bfb-e477de1474ae
```

My htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /asset\.php\?id=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%1\? [R,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /asset.php?id=$1 [L]
```

What should I put into my htaccess file as this is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this code in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+assets/asset\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /assets/%1? [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^assets/([^/]+)/?$ assets/asset.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Ok it works on root folder but what about sub folders?

Comment: You're welcome. For that you will need to create a new question for this describing the requirement clearly.